# Как стилизовать input range по такому принципу

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Не знаю как сделать

1. Шаг через каждые 25 пунктов (пунктир)
2. Разную высоту сначала и в конце полоски, получается она изменяется от 0 до 100 (бэка)
3. Ну и естественно надписи над этими пунктирами
4. Сам ползунок так стилизовать, каплей
5. Как сделать изменение цвета полосы путем применения JS от первого цвета до последнего? Градиентом. Только сейчас обратил внимание, что у меня градиентом после движения ползунка, используется сразу последний цвет и при изменении положения ползунка "наполняется" промежутком необходимый цвет. А мне нужно чтобы ползунок сам наполнял этот промежуток между началом и концом полосы ползунка.

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $('input[type="range"]');
  r.on('mouseenter', function() {
    var p = r.val();
    r.on('click', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
    r.on('mousemove', function() {
      p = r.val();
      console.log(p)
      bg(p);
    });
  });

  function bg(n) {
    r.css({
      'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left ,#ceb8ee 0%,#8a86c3 ' + n + '%,#e8e8e8 ' + n + '%, #e8e8e8 100%)'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  height: 25px;
  background: @white;
  border: 1px solid @btn;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .1s;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  /*   width: 16px;
height: 16px; */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно ли переписывать код js ? Возможно надо считывать позицию курсора и заполнять полосу ? Не могу придумать...

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $('input[type="range"]');
  r.on('mouseenter', function() {
    var p = r.val();
    r.on('click', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
    r.on('mousemove', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
  });

  function bg(n) {
    r.css({
      'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left ,#ceb8ee 0%,#8a86c3 ' + n + '%,#e8e8e8 ' + n + '%, #e8e8e8 100%)'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
}

#slider {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider .triangle {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
    border-left: 600px solid #ffffff;
}


#slider .steps {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.steps .step{
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px dotted #999999;
    width: calc(100%/4);
    height: 16px;
    z-index: 100;
}



input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #8a86c3;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  border-radius: 100% 0% 100% 100%;
  transition: .1s;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  background: #8a86c3;
  border: 1px solid #8a86c3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="steps"><div class="step"></div><div class="step"></div><div class="step"></div><div class="step"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу помочь только с 1 и 2 пунктом. Первое это атрибут step а второе это css clip-path.

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $('input[type="range"]');
  r.on('mouseenter', function() {
    var p = r.val();
    r.on('click', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
    r.on('mousemove', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
  });

  function bg(n) {
    r.css({
      'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left ,#ceb8ee 0%,#8a86c3 ' + n + '%,#e8e8e8 ' + n + '%, #e8e8e8 100%)'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 88%);
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 88%);
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  height: 25px;
  background: @white;
  border: 1px solid @btn;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .1s;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  /*   width: 16px;
height: 16px; */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Я понимаю что есть аттрибут степ, который через каждые 25 меняет положение ползунка. Мне не так надо, видимо не правильно выразился. Мне надо на каждые 25 пунктов изначально уже добавить Пунктирные полоски, которые "перерубают" полоску, видно на картинке. Но ползунок должен двигаться естественно по 1 пункту. Это скорее вопрос CSS блока, но как это дело объединить я не знаю.

2. При КЛИПЕ не работает сам ползунок, его не видно, видимо потому что он тоже режется.